# How can a S3 link only get used from a user who visits my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to prevent a Download Link which I generate via Amazon S3 `url_for`

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(
  :access_key_id => 1234,
  :secret_access_key => abcd
)
object = s3.buckets['bucket'].objects['path/to/object']
object.url_for(:get, { :expires => 20.minutes.from_now, :secure => true }).to_s
```

being spread after a user generated it. The user bought the link via my app and I only want him to download it (solved via the unique token url_for provides) but only from my app.

The problem is that the link can still get c/p and shared all over the web. How do I prevent this from happening by e.g. authorize the referer / tell S3 to only allow access if the DL has happened from my app.

Maybe I also overcomplicate this scenario and there is a much easier solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

Comment: checked it out, seems pretty easy to configure. But I seem to miss one piece of the puzzle because it does not work :)
E.g. this configuration does still allow me to open the file from anywhere:

`<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000/</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>`

Comment: Note: I added the CORS rule to my bucket. I cannot add a CORS rule to a specific file.

Answer (score 1):

Check out CORS, it's a method to block hotlinking files stored in S3 from other websites (only from allowed sources/referrers)
In combination with expiration this should work.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: Thanks for this!
I was also thinking about a very basic solution like this

   `url = object.url_for(:get, { :expires => 1.seconds.from_now, :secure => true }).to_s

    redirect_to url`

when a user hits the Download Button. This instantly creates a DL link and redirects the user to the URL. Link could not get shared by pragmatic users.
Is this too dirty?

Comment: I think you should give more that 1 sec. 5-10 sec is too low for someone to spread the link but also in case of delay may cause problems for users. I think 1 minute would be optimal.
Anyway you should secure your files with CORS just in case something goes wrong sometime...

Comment: Agree. But see above. I somehow have problems using CORS. I added this sample `<CORSConfiguration> <CORSRule> <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000/</AllowedOrigin> <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod> <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod> <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod> <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader> </CORSRule> </CORSConfiguration>` in the CORS settings of my bucket. But it does not work. Also if I add google.com as an origin etc I can still approach the bucket. Maybe I miss some piece of the puzzle :/

Comment: Hmm, now I'm puzzled. I tested this on my site an it doesn't work either. I need to read more on CORS.

Comment: Glad I'm not alone ;) let me know when you made it work. Will also research what this is ...